# Broadcasting Android application using Opentok SDK

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox

Im working on an android application where multiple user subscribe to my stream published from android device. What i want to pull off is, when i click the video of a certain subscriber, all the subscriber(user) will then subscribe to his/her stream rather than mine.
if there is any article or code to suggest me, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a sample to point to but I can tell you how I would solve this.

You will need to communicate to everyone in the Session which stream to  subscribe to. You can use the [signal API](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Session.html#sendSignal-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) in opentok to do this by passing a streamId along. Then when each participant receives that signal they can lookup the corresponding stream and subscribe to it. You will need to make sure that every time a new person joins you also send them a signal saying which stream to subscribe to. You can do this by listening for the [connectionCreated event.](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Session.html#onConnectionCreated-com.opentok.android.Connection-)

If only one participant is allowed to tell everyone who to subscribe to then you might want to have a look at the connection data property of [tokens](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-token/). Then you can add eg. 'admin' as the connection data and then when you receive the signals make sure that they are coming from someone that has 'admin' as their [connection data](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Connection.html#data).

Comment: Can you tell me , how do i make sure that everyone in the session subscribes to a particular stream from a particular person?

Comment: When each participant the signal from admin, how do i lookup the corresponding stream and subscribe to it?

Comment: You will need to keep track of the list of streams yourself. So listen for the streamCreated and streamDestroyed events and add/remove them to your own data structure. Then when you receive a signal you can go through and look up the Stream that goes with the streamId.

Comment: After Sending the streamID to all the clients, what methods should i use to subscribe to that stream as the streamID is a string and the API requires stream to build a subscriber. In other words , how do i use the streamId to subscribe to that stream?

Comment: That's what I meant about keeping track of the list of streams yourself. So you could use eg. a HashMap with the key being the streamId and the value being the stream object. Then you can look up that stream object and use the subscribe method.